# Visual Studio Extensibility: Intercepting file paste event

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-extensions

How do I intercept the file paste event in my Visual Studio extension?
File paste = pasting the whole file in Solution Explorer.

My goal is to apply certain replacements to the copied file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be intercepted using `DTE.Events.CommandEvents` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/envdte.commandevents.aspx)) with `typeof(VSConstants.VSStd97CmdID).GUID` as command guid and `VSConstants.VSStd97CmdID.Paste` as command id.

Example:

```cs
protected override void Initialize() {
    var dte = (DTE)GetService(typeof(DTE));

    var pasteGuid = typeof(VSConstants.VSStd97CmdID).GUID.ToString("B");
    var pasteID = (int)VSConstants.VSStd97CmdID.Paste;

    _pasteEvent = dte.Events.CommandEvents[pasteGuid, pasteID];
    _pasteEvent.BeforeExecute += delegate { Trace.WriteLine("Before paste."); };
    _pasteEvent.AfterExecute += delegate { Trace.WriteLine("After paste."); };
}
```

This is not really perfect as it may intercept paste in other contexts as well, but it a good first step. It is also possible to watch `ItemAdded` event during the paste to get the pasted items.